# NSDictionary leak problem

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad

I have a leak when my app is running on device.
The leak is in the following code-snippet:

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)newDict:(int)index {
 NSLog(@"%@: %s: %i", [self description],__FUNCTION__, index);
 NSString *themePath;
 NSDictionary *themesDict;
 NSMutableArray *themesArray;
 NSMutableDictionary *thisThemeDict;
 if (index < 4) {
  themePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:PATH_THEMES_PLIST ofType:@"plist"];
  themesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:themePath];
  themesArray = [[themesDict objectForKey:KEY_THEMES] mutableCopy];
  thisThemeDict = [[themesArray objectAtIndex:index] mutableCopy];
 } else {
  themePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:PATH_CHARTS_PLIST ofType:@"plist"];
  themesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:themePath];
  themesArray = [[themesDict objectForKey:KEY_THEMES] mutableCopy];  
  thisThemeDict = [[themesArray objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];
 }
 themePath = nil;
 themesDict = nil;
 [themesArray release];
 return thisThemeDict;
}
```

The leak-instrument highlighted the line:

themesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:themePath];

The leaked object is a NSCFString, so I think the problem is with 'themePath'.

I tried several solutions for hours and hours... but without luck.
Can anybody help me out...

thanks xnz

Comment: many, but I don't remember all of them. I tried autorelease on themePath and on themesDict. And I tried stringWithFormat on themePath.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the llvm compiler (Build and analyze in xcode 3.1.2 and later, snow leopard) to locate the error specifically.  If you are using Leopard (10.5) the leaks instrument reports non-existent memory leaks occasionally.  I had the same issue with one of my projects.  The new leaks instrument in Snow Leopard is like 100% better.

[LLVM compiler](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html#llvm-compiler)

Comment: but I have questions: What is llvm compiler? Can I use garbage-collection for i-pad... I think no? And if I release themesDict it will crash with: [CFDictionary release] message send to deallocated object.

Comment: I didn't notice the iphone and ipad tag, oops.  I updated the question.

Comment: My question was a little mal-formed.  What I was trying to say was the LLVM compiler is available in xcode 3.1.2 and later.  So it is available in your xcode, go to build > Build & Analyze

Comment: okay... I will try it tommorrow... now I'm a little destroyed... thank you

Comment: I have used Build & Analyze, but it only shows warnings about unused variables... no possible leak is showing

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shown us is correct with regard to its management of retain counts.  The one thing that could be getting leaked is thisThemeDict, which you return from this method with a +1 retain count.  This means that wherever you call this method, you'll need to release the object it returns at some point.  You should examine how you handle the object this method returns in every place that it is called in your codebase.

Comment: I call this method from two places. The first is: NSMutableDictionary *thisDict = [UIViewController newDict:index];
theModel = [[ThemeDataModel alloc] initWithDictionary:thisDict];
[thisDict release];                                               The second is:                                                      ...  NSMutableDictionary *thisDict = [UIViewController newDict:self.themeIndex];
NSMutableArray *plistArray = [[thisDict objectForKey:KEY_MODULES] mutableCopy];
[thisDict release];

Comment: Ok, if the object being leaked is a string, then you're probably either over-retaining or copying one of the values in the dictionary returned in this method.  Have you tried compiling and analyzing your project?  This will run your code through the clang static analyzer, which is a fast way to identify basic misuses of the retain count.  In Xcode, try going to the Build menu and selecting "Build and Analyze".  It might be able to point you to where you're making the mistake.

Comment: I've done the 'Build and Analyze'... no possible leaks are shown.

Comment: Check your destructors.  Not releasing a member variable in a destructor is a good way to leak without it being found by Clang.

Comment: the problem is fixed... will post solution later... thank you!